# Can apache httpd listen on a unix socket?

Tags: apache-http-server, sockets

I would like `httpd` (Apache 2.4.x) to serve HTTP requests
over a UNIX domain socket. The [*Listen* directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#listen)
doesn’t seem to allow for specifying sockets. Is there perhaps
another (undocumented?, module?) way of getting httpd to use a
socket?

EDIT because some person vaguely demands more “clarity”:

a) HTTP refers to the HTTP protocol.

b) As for UNIX sockets see `unix(7)`. Naturally a `SOCK_STREAM` is used.

Given a client program that is capable of talking a) over a b)
and a server program implemented as an httpd module running on the
same system which already provides a) but over TCP sockets, could
httpd be configured to speak a) over b) as well?

Comment: You may want to have a look at Nginx if you want to connect to Unix sockets with a web server. Personally, I haven't seen anything to indicate Apache is capable of this.

Comment: @Anaksunaman: Nginx is not an option. If it were, it would have been used. The question is specifically about Apache.